# Identifying whether a laptop has HDMI 2.0 or 1.4

Tags: windows-10, laptop, hdmi

I originally asked this question in stackoverflow, but was told it would be more appropriate here:

I have a ASUS ROG GL552VW laptop and am trying to figure out whether the HDMI port on it supports HDMI 2.0. I wish to use it to output 4k content onto a TV. However, after reading the manual, and a few hours of searching online I simply cannot find this information. I also struggled to find it for other laptops too. Is there some driver I can look for on my laptop which would tell me if it does indeed support HDMI 2.0? Or something else?

TL;DR Does this laptop "ASUS ROG GL552VW" support HDMI 2.0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ASUS ROG GL552VW uses the Integrated Intel® HD Graphics 530 which supports 4k @ 60Hz and the GeForce GTX 960M which also supports 4k @ 60 Hz.  So it would very surprising if it did not also support HDMI 2.0 since 2.0 was released 2+ years before this laptop was.

Now having said that, the GeForce website has this to say:

> GeForce GTX 960M
>
> Discover desktop-class gaming on a notebook with GeForce GTX 960M. Driving great gameplay at high settings on 1080p resolutions, packed with inspired graphics technologies, and BatteryBoost for improved battery life you can game longer, unplugged.

So you likely do not want to play games at that resolution.

([Source ASUS](https://www.asus.com/us/Notebooks/ROG-GL552VW/specifications/)) ([Source GeForce](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/notebook-gpus/geforce-gtx-960m))

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So am I correct in thinking I'd be able to watch films on the 4k screen using the Intel HD Graphics 530 at 60 fps, but for GPU intensive games I'd only be able to get 30 fps using the GeForce GTX 960M?

Comment: How many frames you get in a game depends on the game.  4k 60 gps video is much easier to do, but still, very much dependent on which codec your using

Comment: The card itself does support 4K @ 60 Hz, however the HDMI output/port must also support HDMI 2.0... so one thing still needs to be confirmed. I have a GL552VW and I can only get 4k @ 30 Hz, can't yet get 4K @ 60 Hz and I'm still trying to find out which part is the problem.

Answer (score 4):

All GL552VW models have the same HDMI 1.4 port. Even though you may see a difference in the placement of ports, the specs are same.

From https://rog.asus.com/forum/showthread.php?86882-ASUS-ROG-GL552VW-Product-Information:

> HDMI, USB 3.0 Type C and 2x USB 3.0
>   - USB 3.0 Type-C port
>   - Two USB 3.0 ports
>   - HDMI 1.4 port

Answer (score 2):

Chance are it does NOT have an HDMI 2.0 port.  Most laptops even with 4K 60Hz screens only have HDMI 1.4 as that is all the regular Intel HD Graphics chipsets support.